# What types of files does Java's canwrite() apply to?

Tags: java

I need to use it to delete media files. Will canwrite() let me know if there are any locks on the file or does it only apply to text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jtanhlborn has pointed out, `canWrite()` is not what you're looking for. A quick way to check if a `File` is locked is trying to modify the file's name with [`renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) and seeing whether you are successful. For example:

```
File file = new File("testFile.png");
boolean fileLocked = !file.renameTo(file);
```

In the case that the file rename succeeds, `renameTo` will returned `true` and locked will be `false`. Of course, the file name won't be modified since you "renamed" it to its original name.

Comment: do you mean actually changing the file name or just testing if locked comes back true or false? I don't want to actually change the name.

Comment: @Dev-Ria Added something to clarify. The end result is not changing the name at all despite performing a rename operation.

Comment: ok so `!file.renameTo(file)` means if it couldn't rename the file. so filelocked = false means its locked?

Comment: `renameTo` returns `false` if it fails. Therefore, when it fails `fileLocked` is set to `!renameTo` which is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

[`canWrite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) is a permissions test (i.e. a static check based on the file metadata).  it has nothing to do with the file content or any file locks.

Comment: added a link to the javadoc ;)

Comment: I've seen it being used to test whether a file is being used by another process before deleting. Is this the best way to test if a file is being used by another process?

Comment: @Dev-Ria - as i've already pointed out, no, that is meaningless.